# Slight render delay in applying new CSS using React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am noticing several milliseconds of visible delay when applying conditional CSS using React and I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong. It's a very small app I'm creating in order to learn the framework. This is the component causing the problem:

```js
export default function Word({ word, state, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      id='word'
      disabled={state !== 'gameover'}
      onClick={onClick}
      className={state === 'timesup' ? 'timesup' : ''}
      >
      {state === 'playing' && word}
      {state === 'gameover' && 'GO'}
      {state === 'timesup' && 'Time\'s up!'}
    </button>
  )
}
```

In my main `App.js` it is rendered with:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

import Timer from './components/Timer';
import Word from './components/Word';

function App() {
  const timer = 3;
  const [word, setWord] = useState('some word');
  const [state, setState] = useState('gameover');

  const handleStartGame = () => {
    setState('playing');
  }

  const handleTimesUp = async event => {
    setState('timesup');
    await sleep(3000)
    setState('gameover');
  }

  const sleep = ms => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  )

  return (
    <>
      <Timer duration={timer} isRunning={state === 'playing'} timesUp={handleTimesUp} />
      <Word word={word} state={state} onClick={handleStartGame}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't believe it's part of the issue but for the sake of completeless here `Timer.js`:

```js
import { useState } from "react"
import { useEffect } from "react"

export default function Timer({ duration, isRunning, timesUp }) {
  const [time, setTime] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRunning) {
      const timer = time > 0 && setInterval(() => setTime(time - 1), 1000)
      if (time === 0) {
        timesUp()
      }
      return () => clearInterval(timer)
    } else {
      setTime(duration)
    }
  }, [time, isRunning])

  return (
    <div id='timer'>{time}</div>
  )
}
```

And the relevant CSS:

```css
#word {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-3);
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: var(--color-5);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: var(--color-2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
}

#word:disabled {
  color: var(--color-2);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#word.timesup {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

When the state is changed inside `handleTimesUp` there is a noticeable delay between the moment the text changes to "Time's up" and the CSS is applied. For a brief moment the "Time's up" text is still rendered using its previous color.

As I understood it, when I use `setState` on a parent component it triggers a new render for that component as well as its children. So isn't everything then supposed to be drawn at the same time? And what would be the way to avoid this delay?

---

EDIT: The result is identical if I write the `Word` component in this fashion (i.e. not adding the class name in the return statement):

```js
export default function Word({ word, state, onClick }) {
  let className = 'normal'
  if (state === 'timesup') {
    className += ' timesup'
  }

  return (
    <button
      id='word'
      disabled={state !== 'gameover'}
      onClick={onClick}
      className={className}
      >
  // etc
```

Comment: There should be no difference between when the text arrives and the class is applied, the only thing I can think of is perhaps very last-minute lazy loading of the CSS file itself? Do you have a [mre] we could see?

Comment: I've created a minimal reproducible example from my code and edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use precompiled CSS like sCSS?

Comment: I've never used sCSS. How would it affect the issue? Is is for performance? This is an extremely simple app with 4 tiny files and shouldn't be causing performance issues. Also, all other state-based CSS styles that I apply (in the full application) are applied instantly.